# Method push() firebase is fail

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that saves in the BD using the push method:

```
function insertDB(arregloJson){
var db = firebase.database();
var cedula = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <= arregloJson.length; i++) {

while(arregloJson[i].Identificacion != cedula ){
  db.ref('Student').push({
    Nombres  : arregloJson[i].Nombres,
    Identificacion  : arregloJson[i].Identificacion,
    Programa: arregloJson[i].ProgramaEstudiante,
    Direccion: arregloJson[i].DIRECCION,
    Ciudad: arregloJson[i].CIUDAD,
    Departamento: arregloJson[i].DEPARTAMENTO,
    TelFijo: arregloJson[i].TelFijo,
    TelMovil: arregloJson[i].TelMovil,
    Email: arregloJson[i].EMAIL
  }).then(()=>{
    console.info('Guardado Alumno');
  });
  cedula = arregloJson[i].Identificacion;
}
}
db.ref('Test').push({
  Nombre: 'Dummy',
  Apellido: 'Dummy'
}).then(() => {console.info('Prueba guardada')});
}
```

The function saves the student object correctly, but does not save the object test.

The only Error is:

```
[TypeError: arregloJson[i] is undefined
```

Why do not you save in the second JSON object?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your code or where exactly the TypeError gets thrown? The first thing that jumps right at me is your for-loop. Shouldn't it be "i < arregloJson.length" instead of "i <= arregloJson.length"? array[array.length] is always undefined, because indexes go from 0-(length-1)

Comment: Good catch Frede. Voting to close as a typo.